# to_sql pandas method changes the scheme of sqlite tables

Tags: python, pandas

When I write Pandas DataFrame to my SQLite database using [to_sql](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#io-sql) method it changes the `.schema` of my table even if I use `if_exists='append'`. For example after execution

```
with sqlite3.connect('my_db.sqlite') as cnx:
    df.to_sql('Resolved', cnx, if_exists='append')
```

original `.schema`:

```
CREATE TABLE `Resolved` (
`Name` TEXT NOT NULL COLLATE NOCASE,
`Count` INTEGER NOT NULL,
`Obs_Date` TEXT NOT NULL,
`Bessel_year` REAL NOT NULL,
`Filter` TEXT NOT NULL,
`Comments` TEXT COLLATE NOCASE
);
```

changes to:

```
CREATE TABLE Resolved (
                  [Name] TEXT,
  [Count] INTEGER,
  [Obs_Date] TEXT,
  [Bessel_year] REAL,
  [Filter] TEXT,
  [Comments] TEXT

                  );
```

How to save the original scheme of my table? I use pandas 0.14.0, Python 2.7.5

Comment: I don't think that `to_sql` supports `if_exists` param, it doesn't appear in the doc strings

Comment: help(pd.DataFrame.to_sql)

Comment: sorry my mistake, this could be a bug then, do you have sqlalchemy installed

Comment: `cnx`, is this a sqlite connection object or a sqlalchemy engine? + What version of pandas are you using?

Comment: There is possibly a bug that the table name is not escaped. Can you try `pd.io.sql.has_table('Resolved', cnx)` and report the result?

Comment: @joris, the result is `True`

Comment: @user2579566 no matter, it was something else but related. I posted an answer, can you check if that works?

Comment: @user2579566 Actually I was wrong, I don't know where the bug is, and I also cannot reproduce this. Can you provide some more info? `df.info()`, `pd.show_versions()`, a `cursor.execute("select sql from sqlite_master where type = 'table' and name = 'Resolved';"); cursor.fetchall()` before and after the `to_sql` statement. But maybe we can continue the discussion on the issue I opened: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/7355

Comment: Sorry @joris! I'm afraid it was my mistake because I also cannot reproduce this. I can remove this question. But anyway it was very helpful for me. I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Starting from 0.14 (what you are using), the sql functions are refactored to use `sqlalchemy` to improve the functionality`. See the [whatsnew](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#sql) and [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#sql-queries) on this.
The raw sqlite3 connection is still supported as a fallback (but that is the only sql flavor that is supported without sqlalchemy).

Using sqlalchemy should solve the issue. For this you can just create a sqlalchemy engine instead of the direct sqlite connection `cnx`:

```
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('sqlite:///my_db.sqlite')
df.to_sql('Resolved', engine, if_exists='append')
```

But I filed an issue for the case with the sqlite cnx fallback option: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/7355

Comment: When I execute your code I get /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/sqlite/base.py:860: SAWarning: Could not instantiate type <class 'sqlalchemy.sql.sqltypes.INTEGER'> with reflected arguments [u'4']; using no arguments.
  coltype = self._resolve_type_affinity(type_)

Comment: It is a warning I see, but it does also not work? Are the data appended and the scheme not changed?

Comment: Glad it works! But, without using the sqlalchemy engine, you still have the issue? Would you like to further discuss this? (I would like to fix this bug, but I can't reproduce it) See http://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/7355

Comment: Now I have no bug without using the sqlalchemy engine.