# Python Pandas to_sql, how to create a table with a primary key?

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, primary-key, pandasql

I would like to create a MySQL table with Pandas' to_sql function which has a primary key (it is usually kind of good to have a primary key in a mysql table) as so:

```
group_export.to_sql(con = db, name = config.table_group_export, if_exists = 'replace', flavor = 'mysql', index = False)
```

but this creates a table without any primary key, (or even without any index).

The documentation mentions the parameter 'index_label' which combined with the 'index' parameter could be used to create an index but doesn't mention any option for primary keys.

[Documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html)

Comment: @unutbu I think the `index=True` just ensures the index is written to the table and that it is an index in sql, and not yet a primary key

Comment: Yes, index just uses the row number as an index which is not what I want.

Comment: For now, there is not yet support for specifying primary keys (it's on the feature wishlist). Possible workaround to first create the table, and then use the 'append' option in `to_sql`. To create the table, `pd.io.sql.get_schema` could be helpful to create the schema (that then can be adapted/executed to create the table)

Comment: Thanks @joris, you're right `index=True` makes an index, but not a primary key.

Comment: @joris, trying to add to existing table gives error: "NOT NULL constraint failed" for 'id INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL'. How to fill-in PRIMARY KEY?

Comment: @joris, I found AUTOINCREMENT, it was not by default.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Disclaimer: this answer is more experimental then practical, but maybe worth mention.

I found that class `pandas.io.sql.SQLTable` has named argument `key` and if you assign it the name of the field then this field becomes the primary key:

Unfortunately you can't just transfer this argument from `DataFrame.to_sql()` function. To use it you should:

1. create `pandas.io.SQLDatabase` instance

   ```
   engine = sa.create_engine('postgresql:///somedb')
   pandas_sql = pd.io.sql.pandasSQL_builder(engine, schema=None, flavor=None)
   ```
2. define function analoguous to `pandas.io.SQLDatabase.to_sql()` but with additional `*kwargs` argument which is passed to `pandas.io.SQLTable` object created inside it (i've just copied original `to_sql()` method and added `*kwargs`):

   ```
   def to_sql_k(self, frame, name, if_exists='fail', index=True,
              index_label=None, schema=None, chunksize=None, dtype=None, **kwargs):
       if dtype is not None:
           from sqlalchemy.types import to_instance, TypeEngine
           for col, my_type in dtype.items():
               if not isinstance(to_instance(my_type), TypeEngine):
                   raise ValueError('The type of %s is not a SQLAlchemy '
                                    'type ' % col)

       table = pd.io.sql.SQLTable(name, self, frame=frame, index=index,
                        if_exists=if_exists, index_label=index_label,
                        schema=schema, dtype=dtype, **kwargs)
       table.create()
       table.insert(chunksize)
   ```
3. call this function with your `SQLDatabase` instance and the dataframe you want to save

   ```
   to_sql_k(pandas_sql, df2save, 'tmp',
           index=True, index_label='id', keys='id', if_exists='replace')
   ```

And we get something like

```
CREATE TABLE public.tmp
(
  id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('tmp_id_seq'::regclass),
...
)
```

in the database.

PS You can of course monkey-patch `DataFrame`, `io.SQLDatabase` and `io.to_sql()` functions to use this workaround with convenience.

Comment: Nice. Thank you. 
In the end however I found it simpler to just make the table before and append to it.

Comment: I was also hoping that the index_label option of to_sql would help.

Comment: Great answer, unfortunately it doesn't work with MySQL if the key column is a text type because pandas doesn't seem to have a way to specify the key length. It gives error 1170, "BLOB/TEXT column used in key specification without a key length"

Comment: @krvkir Hi, I would like to add `primary key` to in `to_sql` function, but when I wrote `keys='id'` in that function, it says `TypeError: to_sql() got an unexpected keyword argument 'keys'`, do you know the reason why? I use python 3.6.6, postgres 10.3, SQLAlchemy 1.2.15 and pandas 0.23.4, really appreciate for any advice.

Answer (score 79):

Simply add the primary key after uploading the table with pandas.

```
group_export.to_sql(con=engine, name=example_table, if_exists='replace', 
                    flavor='mysql', index=False)

with engine.connect() as con:
    con.execute('ALTER TABLE `example_table` ADD PRIMARY KEY (`ID_column`);')
```

Comment: SQLite does not support this.

Comment: @tomp - Thank you so much and add FIRST to bring index to front if needed `ALTER TABLE `{table_name}` CHANGE `index` `id` int(4) NOT NULL auto_increment FIRST;`

Answer (score 19):

As of pandas 0.15, at least for some flavors, you can use argument `dtype` to define a primary key column. You can even activate `AUTOINCREMENT` this way. For sqlite3, this would look like so:

```
import sqlite3
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'MyID': [1, 2, 3], 'Data': [3, 2, 6]})
with sqlite3.connect('foo.db') as con:
    df.to_sql('df', con=con, dtype={'MyID': 'INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT'})
```

Comment: OP should promote this as the chosen answer as it works quite well.

Comment: @DanSteingart OP asked about MySQL but the string value for dtype is only supported for SQLite. In general, the dtype value needs to be a SQLAlchemy type (such as `Integer()`) so I think it's just an accident that for SQLite the string is passed through and can be used to set a primary key. In other SQL backends, this generally won't work.

Comment: This doesn't work for me - I get the error: `ValueError: The type of col is not a SQLAlchemy type`.

Answer (score 1):

```
with engine.connect() as con:
    con.execute('ALTER TABLE for_import_ml ADD PRIMARY KEY ("ID");')
```

`for_import_ml` is a table name in the database.

Adding a slight variation to tomp's answer (I would comment but don't have enough reputation points).

I am using PGAdmin with Postgres (on Heroku) to check and it works.

Answer (score 0):

`automap_base` from `sqlalchemy.ext.automap` (tableNamesDict is a dict with only the Pandas tables):

```
metadata = MetaData()
metadata.reflect(db.engine, only=tableNamesDict.values())
Base = automap_base(metadata=metadata)
Base.prepare()
```

Which would have worked perfectly, except for one problem, **automap requires the tables to have a primary key**. Ok, no problem, I'm sure Pandas `to_sql` has a way to indicate the primary key... nope. This is where it gets a little hacky:

```
for df in dfs.keys():
    cols = dfs[df].columns
    cols = [str(col) for col in cols if 'id' in col.lower()]
    schema = pd.io.sql.get_schema(dfs[df],df, con=db.engine, keys=cols)
    db.engine.execute('DROP TABLE ' + df + ';')
    db.engine.execute(schema)
    dfs[df].to_sql(df,con=db.engine, index=False, if_exists='append')
```

I iterate thru the `dict` of `DataFrames`, get a list of the columns to use for the primary key (i.e. those containing `id`), use `get_schema` to create the empty tables then append the `DataFrame` to the table.

Now that you have the models, you can explicitly name and use them (i.e. `User = Base.classes.user`) with `session.query` or create a dict of all the classes with something like this:

```
alchemyClassDict = {}
for t in Base.classes.keys():
    alchemyClassDict[t] = Base.classes[t]
```

And query with:

```
res = db.session.query(alchemyClassDict['user']).first()
```

Comment: [pd.io.sql.get_schema is not in the public interface](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/9960) so not good to rely on it.

Also the code will only work if the dataframe doesn't have an index. Otherwise have to use something like `schema = pd.io.sql.get_schema(df.reset_index(), table_name, con=db.engine, keys=cols)`