# Specifying the schema in Pandas to_sql

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, sqlalchemy

From the source of [to_sql](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html), I can see that it gets mapped to an Meta Data object `meta = MetaData(con, schema=schema)`. However, I can't find SQLAlchemy docs that tell me how to define the Schema for MySQL

How do I specify the schema string ?

Comment: See [here](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/core/metadata.html#specifying-the-schema-name) for the docs. But as far as I know, MySQL does not support "schema's" in the sense of a "subcollection of tables" ("schema" is a but dubious word with multiple meanings). You will have to clarify your question with what exactly you mean with "how to define the Schema"

Comment: Oh, what I mean is, I want to define the type of each column, their properties(index,key) etc

Comment: This is done automatically by `to_sql`. If you want to overwrite the used column types, see the [`dtype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#sql-data-types) keyword argument. And if you want to customize this even more, probably best to make the sql table manually, and then use `to_sql(...., if_exists='append')` to append the data to that created table.

Comment: That's actually how I am doing it right now, using the engine to send raw sql queries. Figured it might be easier using schema thingy. What does the schema variable define anyway ?

Comment: See the link I posted. Most other databases (but not MySQL) have a 'schema' concept of a group of database tables that eg are owned/accessible by a specific user. See eg http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/ddl-schemas.html

Comment: [The highest voted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40770849/6560549) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30867390/6560549) suggests altering the table definition after pandas creates it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The schema parameter in `to_sql` is confusing as the word "schema" means something different from the general meaning of "table definitions". In some SQL flavors, notably postgresql, a schema is effectively a namespace for a set of tables.

For example, you might have two schemas, one called `test` and one called `prod`. Each might contain a table called `user_rankings` generated in pandas and written using the `to_sql` command. You would specify the `test` schema when working on improvements to user rankings. When you are ready to deploy the new rankings, you would write to the `prod` schema.

As others have mentioned, when you call `to_sql` the table definition is generated from the type information for each column in the dataframe. If the table already exists in the database with **exactly the same structure**, you can use the `append` option to add new data to the table.

Comment: Then, how do you specify schema in to_sql?

Comment: I think you use```dtype```?

Answer (score 2):

```
DataFrame.to_sql(self, name, con, schema=None, if_exists='fail', index=True, index_label=None, chunksize=None, dtype=None, method=None)
```

Just use [schema parameter](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html). But note that schema is not odbc driver.

Comment: He is asking what the string for the schema should look like. I am also  wondering the same.

Comment: @NoahGary, string schema for direct DB requests. If you using Pandas, you have to follow it syntax

Comment: Even a couple years later, this answered my question... Thanks!

Answer (score -6):

Starting from the [Dialects](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/dialects/index.html) page of the SQLAlchemy documentation, select documentation page of your dialect and search for `create_engine` to find example on how to create it.

Even more concise overview you can get on [Engine Configuration](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/core/engines.html) page for all supported dialects.

Verbatim extract for `mysql`:

```
# default
engine = create_engine('mysql://scott:tiger@localhost/foo')

# mysql-python
engine = create_engine('mysql+mysqldb://scott:tiger@localhost/foo')

# MySQL-connector-python
engine = create_engine('mysql+mysqlconnector://scott:tiger@localhost/foo')

# OurSQL
engine = create_engine('mysql+oursql://scott:tiger@localhost/foo')
```

Then pass this `engine` to the `to_sql(...)` of pandas' DataFrame.

Comment: What I meant was how should I format the Schema sting of to_sql of pandas .

Comment: Do not the links provided in the answer actually answer this question?

Comment: They don't seem to for mysql,if they do, can you summarize them here ?

Comment: 1) They are just below on the second link in the answer (http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/core/engines.html#mysql); 2) It would have been useful if you specified `mysql` in your question or a tag.

Comment: Please answer the questions in a relevant way.