# force pandas to create an key for the table when inserting a dataframe into an sqlite database

Tags: python, sqlite, pandas

When using pandas to insert data from a dataframe into an sqlite database can you feed it a column to create as the primary key for indexing? is this done automatically when pandas inserts the data or can you supply a parameter?

Comment: possible answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30867390/python-pandas-to-sql-how-to-create-a-table-with-a-primary-key  ?