# dataframe.to_sql index as primary key in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, pandas, sqlalchemy

I have a dataframe with an index that I want to store in a postgresql database. For this I use `df.to_sql(table_name,engine,if_exists='replace', index=True,chunksize=10000)`

The index column from the pandas dataframe is copied to the database but is not set as primary key.

There are two solutions that require an additional step:

1. specify a schema `df.to_sql(schema=)` [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html)
2. Set the primary key after the table is ingested. query:

   ALTER TABLE table_name ADD PRIMARY KEY (id_column_name)

Is there a way to set the primary key without specifying the schema or altering the table?

Comment: [This question has a couple suggestions for setting the primary key in a MySQL table, which would likely apply to postgresql as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30867390/python-pandas-to-sql-how-to-create-a-table-with-a-primary-key)

However, it would appear that simply adding a line to to use the ALTER TABLE would be the fastest and easiest way to set a primary key.

Answer (score 2):

After calling to_sql:

```
import sqlalchemy
engine = create_engine()
engine.execute('ALTER TABLE schema.table ADD PRIMARY KEY (keycolumn);')
```

Unfortunately, pandas.to_sql doesn't set primary key, it even also destructs the primary key of existing table. One must aware for the primary keys.