# Is it possible to create foreign keys with pandas to_sql

Tags: pandas, sqlalchemy, pandas-to-sql

I have two `DataFrame`s that have a `ForeignKey` based relationship, a field in the first `DataFrame` is a `ForeignKey` to the `Id` of the second `DataFrame`. When I use `pandas`'s `to_sql` method, The relationship is not created in the destination database. Is there a way to create the relationship with `to_sql`?

Comment: Pandas has no concept of primary or foreign key, or indeed any relations between dataframes, so your dataframes don't have this relationship (except in the sense that it exists in your mind). As such it is not possible for Pandas to add this to the sql commands. You can only add the keys separately using the same SQL connection object. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30867390/python-pandas-to-sql-how-to-create-a-table-with-a-primary-key) for more.

Answer (score 0):

The pandas.to_sql() will only convert the data existing on your dataframe and it does not allow to select the foreign keys and consequently creating the relationship table. however you can solve this in two ways:

1. Make a pandas.merge() to get the relationship table
2. After converting pandas to sql, use sql library (e.g, sqlite) to create a relationship table with the foreign keys.

I hope this helps you.